# Angular UI Router - $stateParams has attributes but can´t access them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angular-ui-router

So I'm sending via email a link to my website where it has a code as a parameter, something like:

localhost:8080/app/recover_password/12345678

On my routes config i have:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, VIEWS_PREFIX) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

    $stateProvider.state("recover_password", {
        url : "/recover_password/:code",
        templateUrl : VIEWS_PREFIX + "recover_password_form_view.html",
        controller : "login_controller"
    });
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $stateParams, login_services) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log($stateParams.code);     
        }
    });
});
```

If I try to read the params like that I'm getting an undefined, but if I read them like:

```
console.log($stateParams);
```

I actually get an object with the code in it.

Here's a capture of what I'm getting in the console when I only log $stateParams:

[image]

I have also tried accessing to it like $stateParams["code"] but still get undefined.

Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that I had to use `toParams` from the $stateChangeStart function instead of $stateParams.

It's working with that.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the solution that worked for you. It'll be super helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inject `$stateParams` in the method as well like this:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $stateParams, login_services) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, $stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams.code);     
    }
    });
});
```

Then access it.